# redis celeryd and apache

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I'm a bit new to redis and celery.  Do I need to restart celeryd and redis every time I restart apache? I'm using celery and redis with a django project hosted on webfaction.

Thanks for the info in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you're running Daemon processes of Redis and Celery you do not need to restart them when you restart Apache.

Generally, you will need to restart them when you make configuration changes to either Redis or Celery as the applications are dependent on eachother.

Comment: yeah, I'm running them as Daemons .  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Does that include when you make code changes (which is the main reason I restart Apache)?